# Debugging- Thread.State: WAITING? What does that mean?

Tags: java, android, debugging

UPDATE: I saw the explanation as someone marked it as a duplicate, but how can this be fixed?

I am new to the android debugger can someone help me understand what this means. Thank you!!

when i click on the underlined text it has me choose between a .class and a .java file and the .java file has a bunch of errors and the .class doesn't have errors but it says decompiled file. Thank you for any help/ explanations! 
[image]

Comment: How can *what* be fixed?

Comment: the error? Because this is what I believe is crashing my app..what steps should I take?

Comment: Sorry, what error?

Comment: I am new sorry for the confusion but the red highlights on the left aren't they errors?

Comment: No, they're just blocked/waiting threads.

Comment: how would I unblock them(is that the correct term)?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: well i thought that is the reason my app is crashing... would it not be?

Comment: I don't see why they would be connected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158912/discussion-between-tff-ghb-and-shmosel).